# How to pass all form data in single GET parameter in Symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm building Symfony form:

```
    $builder
        ->add('myEntity', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => MyEntity::class
        ])
        ->add('anotherEntity', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => AnotherEntity::class
        ])
    ;
```

When I submit this form, all it's parameters are passing as separate GET parameters

`http://my.url/?myEntity=foo&anotherEntity=bar`

I want to put them together in a single array variable

`http://my.url/?singleVar[myEntity]=foo&singleVar[anotherEntity]=bar`

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of all of them to `myArray[]`, then you will be able to access them using `myArray[0] .. [1]` .. etc

Comment: No, I can't: `Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":")`

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model that holds your two entities and simply create the form for that:

AppBundle\Model\MyModel.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use AppBundle\Entity\AnotherEntity;

class MyModel
{
    private $myEntity;
    private $anotherEntity;

    public function getMyEntity()
    {
        return $this->myEntity;
    }

    public function setMyEntity(MyEntity $entity)
    {
        $this->myEntity = $entity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAnotherEntity()
    {
        return $this->anotherEntity;
    }

    public function setAnotherEntity(AnotherEntity $entity)
    {
        $this->anotherEntity = $entity;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

AppBundle\Form\MyModelType.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

use AppBundle\Model\MyModel;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use AppBundle\Entity\AnotherEntity;

class MyModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('myEntity', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => MyEntity::class
            ])
            ->add('anotherEntity', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => AnotherEntity::class
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => MyModel::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your Controller and Action:

```
<?php

use AppBundle\Model\MyModel;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use AppBundle\Entity\AnotherEntity;

use AppBundle\Form\MyModelType;

// In your action:

$model = new MyModel();

$form = $this->createForm(new MyModelType(), $model, ['method' => 'GET']);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
{
    // $model->getMyEntity() and $model->getAnotherEntity() contain the set entities.
}
```

This is dry-coded, so there might be a typo here and there, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work: `MyModel` is populating by needed values, but these values are still passing through the separate GET-parameters.